# KeePass Password Safe 2.12: Unhiding Passwords?

Tags: passwords, keepass

KeePass 2.12 - Turning off hidden password - When I open an entry, the password is disguised by asterisks. How do I turn off this feature so that I can recall previously inputted passwords?

Comment: I was looking for unhiding the master KeePass password, opened a new thread for those interested: https://superuser.com/questions/1296552/hotkey-to-unhide-the-master-password-of-keepass/1296906#1296906

Answer (score 67):

## Edit

Easier way: `View > Configure Columns... > Asterisks`

This lets you change the setting and set a keyboard shortcut.

Or as it is pre-configured, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>!

I had the same question and have found a better solution thanks to answering this question.

---

The menu item seems to have disappeared somewhere during a version update.

To manually change this setting look in the file `KeePass.config.xml` and find the following tag:

```
<Column>
<Type>UserName</Type>
<CustomName />
<Width>204</Width>
<HideWithAsterisks>true</HideWithAsterisks>
</Column>
```

Change `HideWithAsterisks` from `true` to `false`.

Only downside is you can't toggle it easily.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I'm not sure why you lost the ability to just press Ctrl+H to toggle the asterisks on and off in the entry list but I am using version 2.19 now and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In the 'Edit Entry' window, click on the little box (show/hide password using asterisks) next to the password box. It will show the password in plain text.

KeePass will not remember this setting as default. If you want KeePass to always remember your setting, you should go to `Tools > Options > Advanced` and mark the checkbox of

> Remember password hiding setting in
>   'Edit Entry' window

which stands at the 5th line from the bottom.

Answer (score 10):

I used this simple solution after upgrading to 2.18, to unhide passwords

- Click on `View`
- Then `Config Columns`
- Then on the `Passwords Column`
- Then **uncheck** the `Hide Data Using Asterisks`

Answer (score 1):

Hit **Ctrl+H**. That's easiest way.

(Password hide/unhide states are saved even if the program is closed)

Answer (score 0):

right click the "Password" title and it shows an option to unhide. just found this out. ctrl+h didn't work and i couldn't find another way to unhide passwords.

Answer (score -1):

Click on menu "View"
Then choose command "Config Columns"
Then clic on the Passwords line
Then uncheck the "Hide Data Using Asterisks" which appear suddenly on the back of the dialogue box