# Shortcut to unhide the master password of KeePass

Tags: passwords, keepass, passphrase

I have a long password (passphrase) and so I often have to check if I typed it correctly. So I have to move my hand from the keyboard to the mouse to click that unhide button.

Is there a hotkey, faster way to show/hide the password from the keyboard?

I would not like to shorten the password trusting that the key won't autoload / someone looking for it will not find it. An acceptable shortcut would be to use my laptop's fingerprint sensor, but that is not doable as of [2017 / KeePass forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329221/thread/cc749cae/) and [2017 / Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/KeePass/comments/7276eh/unlock_keepass_236_with_fingerprint/).

Answer (score 0):

Inside of KeePass there is a hotkey Ctrl+H to show/hide the password when adding / editing an entry but that doesn't work on startup, please feel free to correct me if you have found a direct hotkey for showing/hiding the master password when entering into KeePass.

My workaround is to just use this sequence of keys until there will be a real hotkey for it: <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd> then <kbd>Backarrow</kbd> to edit the now visible password.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you event don't need to press the `backarrow`. Just pressing `tab` then `space` with keepass v2.38 on secure desktop.

You have right there is no direct hotkey for that.

Instead you should consider an easier passphrase + a key.

An alternative you may like is the plugin "quick unlock". Depending of the settings you will have to write your master password only once then you will use the "quick" password to open the db.

For a secure keepass the idea is to keep your DB closed and open it only when needed.