# Keepass 2.54. All my saved password changed / encrypted

Tags: passwd

Please help
I have opened my database regularly and i noticed that ALL my saved password are encrypted.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: That's how keepass actually WORKS! [See here](https://keepass.info/help/base/security.html). If you need to see your passwords, [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/185239/keepass-password-safe-2-12-unhiding-passwords)

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you write that your passwords are encrypted. The point of Keepass is to keep your passwords safe and that is the reason your password database is encrypted with a [master key that consists of a password and possibly other items](https://keepass.info/help/base/keys.html).

Comment: How are you opening the database? Through the Keepass interface?

Comment: I use KeyPass here. Open it. View, Configure Columns, Uncheck "asterisks" beside password.  This will allow passwords to display